# xampp set stable conecction with server

Tags: apache, xampp, virtual, virtualhost

i'm host site using xampp virtual host,on windows VPS.All configurations are correctly.But when first time load site no any problems.when try to load site after 10 -15 sec site not be load show

> This site can’t be reached www.xxx.com took too long to respond.
>   Search Google for xxx
>   ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

i also allow Apache server and port 80 access through the firewall.
uninstall everything and do lots of changes.but no any solution for this.

if any one know any tip or solution please share with me.
Thank you

Comment: What do the performance statistics say on the server?  Do you have enough cpu, ram, ...?

Comment: RAM 2GB,intel(R) xeon(R) cpue5 @2.00GHZ

Comment: I meant while it is running, check your performance statistics and see if you are running out.